# can't parse header sent with an array buffer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket

i am sending a file through web socket like this:

```
const handleFileSelect = async (e) => {
        const file = e.target.files[0]
        const fileStream = file.stream()
        

        const writableStream = new WritableStream({
            write: chunk => {
                const header = {
                    type: 'file_send'
                }
                const headerBuf = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(header))
                //server assumes max header size is 100bytes
                const combinedBuf = new Uint8Array(100 + chunk.byteLength)
                combinedBuf.set(headerBuf, 0)
                combinedBuf.set(chunk, 100)
                ws.send(combinedBuf)

            }
        })
        await fileStream.pipeTo(writableStream)
    }
```

and the server side code is:

```
ws.on('message', async (data) => {
                //assuming max header size is 100bytes 
                const headerBytes = data.slice(0, 100)
                const headerString = new TextDecoder().decode(headerBytes)
                try {
                    const header = JSON.parse(headerString)
                    console.log('success', header.type)
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log('couldn\'t parse:', headerString)
                    console.log(error.message)
                }
}
```

and the output is :

```
couldn't parse: {"type":"file_send"}
Unexpected token  in JSON at position 19
```

according to output  `headerString` should be parsable why is it throwing an error